# Setting up google analytics for main domain and sub directory with wordpress installed in both?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have a main website (WWW.XYZ.COM). Under it I plan to have a blog (WWW.XYZ.COM/BLOG).

Both domain and sub-directory has 2 different and separate wordpress installations. I want to track my users and find out how they interact. My main website is for a different purpose while the blog is for marketing etc.

Do you think it is best to have two separate analytic account or is there a way to study each traffic individually under one account? I use a wordpress plugin :https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp?filter=5 to get analytics on my admin panel directly.

I want to see people visiting my main website through the blog or vice versa. I also want the clear source of the traffic (Social media-->blog-->main website for example).

I am totally new to analytics. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal setup would be,

Creating a single Account,
`MyBusiness`

inside which create one Property `MySite`

And create three `Views`

`All Website Data` will report the collective performance of your site and blog. You will have to add `Filters` to the views `Site` and `Blog`

`Site` should have an exclude filter for excluding urls containing `www.xyz.com/blog`

`Blog` should have an include filter for including traffic contaning `www.xyz.com/blog`

```
MyBusiness
    MySite
        All Website Data
        Site
        Blog
```

Additional Readings and Source

- [Predefiened Filters for subdirectories](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en#PredefinedFilters)
- [Managing Filters at View level](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en#ManageFiltersViewLevel)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I got the perfect sense.